# Set Firefox Preferences in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

How do you set firefox preferences in nightwatch? I would like to do the equivalent in java with nightwatch.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "de");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I have this working in chrome, but again I can't figure out how to do it in Firefox.

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "acceptSslCerts": true,
  "chromeOptions" :{
    "prefs": {
      "intl.accept_languages":"fr"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to create a Firefox profile for your Nightwatch test.

### 1) Create a new Firefox profile:

In a terminal, execute this command : "**firefox -p**"
Then create a profil with the name "**webdriver**".

### 2) Configure the new profile

Go to this config page with the url : **about:config**
Search the name "**intl.accept_languages**" and update the value.
Exit Firefox for now.

### 3) Configure Nightwatch to use the new profile

1. "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "**webdriver**"
2. List item  "browserName" : "**firefox**"

Be careful ! it is not a "desiredCapability" parameter.

**Solution 1:** (test config)

```
{
  "yourTest" : {
    "default" : {
       ...
       "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "webdriver",
       "launch_url": "http://localhost:3000",
       "desiredCapabilities" : {
         "browserName" : "firefox",
         "javascriptEnabled" : true,
         "acceptSslCerts" : true
    }
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:** (global config)

```
{
  ...
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "webdriver"
    }
  },
  ...
  "yourTest": {
    "default": {
        "launch_url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "desiredCapabilities" : {
            "browserName" : "firefox",
            "javascriptEnabled" : true,
            "acceptSslCerts" : true
        }
    },
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

check the selenium settings : http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#selenium-settings

Comment: Thanks for your response Nico. I've seen this solution in a few places, ex https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Enable-Firebug-in-Firefox-for-Nightwatch-tests . I don't like it however since I can only use it on that machine where the profile is created. I'd like to have a solution that will work on all machinces, like it does for chrome.

Comment: unfortunately, if you inspect the source code of nightwatch (/lib/runner/selenium.js), you will see than it simply transfers a list of arguments to the selenium driver. So the limitation comes from the firefox driver... There is no client argument about your requirement : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver